# Create jstree in rails with json data using the ajax config option for association parent => children

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1, jstree

My model is:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :parent, :foreign_key => :project_id, :class_name => "Project"
    has_many :children, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "Project", :foreign_key => :project_id
```

[jquery tree plugin](http://www.jstree.com/) with json_data example:

```
$(function () {
    $("#demo2").jstree({ 
        "json_data" : {
            "ajax" : {
                "url" : "/static/v.1.0pre/_docs/_json_data.json",
                "data" : function (n) { 
                    return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 }; 
                }
            }
        },
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data" ]
});
});
```

and the basic structure to supply data in the json format is:

```
{ 
    "data" : {
        "title" : "The node title",

    // omit `attr` if not needed; the `attr` object gets passed to the jQuery `attr` function
    "attr" : { "id" : "node_identificator", "some-other-attribute" : "attribute_value" } },
    // `state` and `children` are only used for NON-leaf nodes
    "state" : "closed", // or "open", defaults to "closed"
    "children" : [ /* an array of child nodes objects */ ]
}
```

I want to create the jstree for a collection of projects dynamically. this collection can have childs, and each child childs and so on. my controller already responds to json and in view I have now the code to create the tree.

I test with this json data example and it creates the tree that I want to:

```
{
"data" : {
    "title" : "Projectos",
    "attr" : { "href" : "/projects"  } }, 
    "children" : [  { 
        "data" : {
            "title" : "teste",
            "attr" : { "href" : "/projects/7"  , "class" : "selected"  } }, 
            "state" : "open" ,
            "children" : [  { 
                "data" : { 
                    "title" : "teste_1",
                    "attr" : { "href" : "/projects/9"  } },
                    "children" : [  ] } 
            ] } , { 
"data" : { 
    "title" : "teste1",
    "attr" : { "href" : "/projects/8"  } }, 
    "children" : [  ] } 
], "state" : "open" }
```

I want to generate json data automatically to my collection of projects following the schema example above. Any suggestions?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. What can't you make work? The dynamic part or ... ?

Comment: At the time i couldn't make to work the dynamic part. a few days later i got it! view my edit

Answer (score -2):

The OP wrote:

> I solved the problem. Solution was in some functions below:
>
> ```
> def tree(id_node_selected)
>
>   if id_node_selected.to_i==0             parentes=[]         else
>       parentes=Project.find(id_node_selected).getPais         end
>
>   filhos = ""         if !@projects.empty?            @projects.each_with_index do
>    |p,i|
>           filhos += p.to_node(id_node_selected,parentes)
>           if i < @projects.count-1
>               filhos += ","
>           end             end         end
>
>   str = " {
>           \"data\" : {
>           \"title\" : \"Projectos\",
>           \"attr\" : { \"href\" : \"/projects\" "
>
>   if id_node_selected=="0"            str += " , \"class\" : \"selected\" "
>   end
>
>   if filhos==""           str +=  " } }, \"children\" : [ ] } "       else            str
>     +=    " } }, \"children\" : [ " + filhos + " ], \"state\" : \"open\" } "      end
>
>   return str  end
>
> def pais(array)
>
>   if !self.parent.nil?            array << self.parent.id
>       self.parent.pais(array)         end
>
>   return array    end
>
>  def getPais      pais = []
>
>   res = self.pais(pais)
>
>   return pais     end
>
>  def to_node(id_node_selected,pais)
>
>   str = " { \"data\" : { \"title\" : \"#{self.name}\",
>           \"attr\" : { \"href\" : \"/projects/" + self.id.to_s + "\" "
>
>   if id_node_selected==self.id.to_s           str += " , \"class\" :
>     \"selected\" "            if !self.children.empty?
>           str += " } }, \"state\" : \"open\" , \"children\" : [ "             else
>           str +=  " } }, \"children\" : [ "           end         else            if !pais.empty? && pais.include?(self.id)
>           str += " } }, \"state\" : \"open\" , \"children\" : [ "
>           pais.delete(self.id)            else
>           str +=  " } }, \"children\" : [ "           end         end
>
>   filhos = ""         if !self.children.empty?
>       self.children.each_with_index do |c,i|
>           filhos += c.to_node(id_node_selected,pais)
>           if i < self.children.count-1
>               filhos += ","
>           end             end         end
>
>   str += filhos + " ] } "
>
>   return str  end
> ```

Comment: ([Answered in a question edit and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).)